# Unity configuration using web.config

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, web-config, unity-container

I have the following code :

```
using System.Web.Http;
using Coben.DataAccess.Tests.Constructiv.CentralDB.Contracts.ServiceContracts;
using Coben.Person.DataAccess;
using Constructiv.CentralDB.Contracts.ServiceContracts;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration;
using Unity.WebApi;

namespace CoBen.UI
{
    public static class UnityConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterComponents()
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();

            container.RegisterInstance<IPersonService>(new PersonServiceMock().Mock);
            container.RegisterType<PersonRepository>();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
        }
    }
}
```

This configures my dependency injection.
But I would like to do the same from my web.config.

i have the following :

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
<alias alias="IPersonService" type="Constructiv.CentralDB.Contracts.ServiceContracts.IPersonSercice, Constructiv.CentralDB.Contracts.ServiceContracts" />
<namespace name="Coben.DataAccess.Tests.Constructiv.CentralDB.Contracts.DataContracts.Persons" />
<assembly name="Coben.DataAccess.Tests.Constructiv.CentralDB.Contracts.DataContracts.Persons" />
<container>
  <register type="IPersonService" name="special" mapTo="PersonServiceMock().Mock" />    
</container>
```

But when i do it like this I get an error message :

The type name or alias IPersonService could not be resolved. Please check your configuration file and verify this type name.

What am I doing wrong or what am I not seeing ?

Update:
I know get the following error :
The type name or alias Constructiv.CentralDB.Contracts.ServiceContracts.IPersonService, Constructiv.CentralDB.Contracts.ServiceContracts could not be resolved. Please check your configuration file and verify this type name.

My config looks as follows:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration" />
</configSections>
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
<container>        
    <register type="Constructiv.CentralDB.Contracts.ServiceContracts.IPersonService, Constructiv.CentralDB.Contracts.ServiceContracts"                  
        mapTo="Coben.DataAccess.Tests.Constructiv.CentralDB.Contracts.DataContracts.Persons.PersonServiceMock().Mock, Coben.DataAccess.Tests.Constructiv.CentralDB.Contracts.DataContracts.Persons" />    
</container>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to configure your instance of the UnityContainer with the settings from the web.config.

```
UnityConfigurationSection section = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");
section.Configure(_container);
```